# How can I create a function to calculate the win percentage of a game as you play more games?

Tags: python, append

I have been trying to create a function to do this as practice. I haven't been coding for long at all. I have tried many things but my current piece of code is as follows:

```
print("If win, type 1. If lose, type 0")
result_list = []
result = input("game result? ")
if result == 1:
    result_list.append(1)
else:
    result_list.append(0)
    
percent = (sum(result_list)/len(result_list)) * 100
print("the win percentage is",percent,"%")
```

I would like to be able to input the number 1 for a win and have this add to the currently empty list. At the moment the result will always come out as 0%. Am I just doing everything wrong?

Comment: `input` returns a string. ;)

Comment: Thank You. Only now there is a new problem. I can type 1 and get 100% but if I then run again with a loss, the percentage is 0 instead of 50%.

Comment: What version of Python do you use ?

Comment: I use 3.9.6 but I usually run it in Spyder first which uses 3.8

Comment: You re-run the program ? That's normal then, the memory is lost from one run to the next. You might want a loop (for / while ?)

Comment: Is there a way to fix this or should I move to another project? I had for loops but I don't really understand them so it doesn't work.

Comment: Add a loop. I don't get how changing project would fix this. For loop example for you: `for _ in range(NUMBER_TEST):` and indent what is below

Answer (score 0):

Code example:

```
results = []

for _ in range(10):
    result_list.append(int(input("game result? ")))

percent = (sum(result_list)/len(result_list)) * 100
print("the win percentage is",percent,"%")
```

You can move the 2 last lines & change the 10 from the for loop to see the effect of a for loop ;)

Comment: Thank you! I've done this and it works to input the result for a set number of games. Is there a way to make this continuous. What I mean is having the ability to type in the result of a game and have the result updated in the list as well as the percentage change correctly?

Comment: Then just try indenting in various ways ;) BTW, if this answer is OK for you, don't hesitate to accept it